# Angular Json data display in component html

Tags: angular, angular8

I am using Angular 8.

On my app.component.html I am displaying some json data linke this:

```
{{ myJsonData }}
```

This display is coming out like this:

```
{"information":"Information One","output":[{"ipaddress":"192.168.2.1","sName":"R45665"},{"ipaddress":"192.168.2.2","sName":"H4433D"}]}
```

But I need it to display like this:

```
{
    "information":"Information One",
    "output":[
        {
            "ipaddress":"192.168.2.1",
            "sName":"R45665"
        },
        {
            "ipaddress":"192.168.2.2",
            "sName":"H4433D"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried `{{ myJsonData | json }}`

But that just gives my lots of backslashes so makes the problem worse.

How can I do this?

Comment: its because its not json but a string use `JSON.parse(myJsonData)`

Answer (score 3):

Try using `<pre>` tag,

```
<pre class="list-group-item-text"> {{ myJsonData | json }} </pre>
```

[`STACKBLITZ DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxvb9m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: This gives me this result: {\"information\":\"Information One\",\"output\":[{\"ipaddress\":\"192.168.2.1\",\"sName\":\"R45665\"},{\"ipaddress\":\"192.168.2.2\",\"sName\":\"H4433D\"}]}

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to pretty print the json output.
its the pre tag you need for this.

your response to the controller comes this way..

```
{"information":"Information One","output":[{"ipaddress":"192.168.2.1","sName":"R45665"},{"ipaddress":"192.168.2.2","sName":"H4433D"}]}
```

in your controller file lets assume its assigned to the response.

```
myJsonData = JSON.stringify(response);
```

in your html view you can then use this..

```
<pre class="~~"> {{ myJsonData }} </pre>
```

Comment: Can't do that...I get: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'myJsonData[]'

Comment: okay maybe thats why you had to use the json pipe filter. because if you posted how you received the json to the variable. then i would have understood better.

Comment: The data is added using .push()